# How do I target a specific commit SHA with capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am wondering how I can target a specific commit SHA in Git for deployment, using Capistrano? It should be something like

```
cap deploy --version=<sha targeted>
```

Can't seem to find the answer to this after a lot of searching.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**For Capistrano 2.9 until 3.0:**

```
cap -S revision=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993 deploy
```

**For older versions of Capistrano**, you can deploy a particular git commit/tree/branch/tag by doing this:

```
cap -s branch=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993 deploy
```

In some cases there may be a need of specifying the Environment as an argument as well. `production` is just an example.

```
cap production -S revision=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993 deploy
```

Comment: is that the SHA for a specific commit?

Comment: The branch will be passed to git with "git checkout <branch>", so a commit id should work just as fine as a tree id, branch name, etc.

Comment: this answer doesn't work for me, see @eahanson 's answer below.

Comment: The original answer was pretty old, updated to reflect changes in Capistrano.

Comment: For Capistrano 3, please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036175/how-to-deploy-a-specific-revision-with-capistrano-3

Comment: `set :branch, 'SHA'` works uniformly in Capistrano 2 & 3

Answer (score 17):

molf's answer didn't work for me (using capistrano 2.11.2). I had to use "revision" instead of branch, like this:

```
cap -S revision=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993 deploy
```

Comment: Working 100% fine in 2.14.2

Comment: Well, 2.11.2 is above 2.9, and you use the syntax mentioned for above 2.9. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @kik molf changed the answer after my comment

Answer (score 14):

**Capistrano 3**

In your `deploy.rb` or stage-specific file like `config/deploy/production.rb`

```
set :branch, ENV.fetch('REVISION', 'master')
```

This allows you to point to a specific git revision. It accepts a SHA but also anything that resolves to a real revision (e.g. git tag, annotated tag, or branch).

Use it on the command line by setting the `REVISION` environment variable, e.g.

```
bundle exec cap production deploy REVISION=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993

bundle exec cap staging deploy REVISION=my-topic-branch
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the branch as a command line argument?

Comment: I don't know a way to do that.

Comment: @marcovtwout yes that's possible, see the updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ask :branch, 'master'

Prompts for input but defaults to 'master' if you press return.