# How to deploy LAMP app with capistrano?

Tags: php, capistrano

I am new to LAMP as well as capistrano and I am totally confused how to start deploying a LAMP application with capistrano. I could find the solution Rails App and git but that is not working in my case using php and svn. I am getting following error while executing deploy setup command:
(Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure your meant `LAMP` ?

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue. It was due to SSH account. I used following command "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" to resolve it. But now I need to understand how I can provide a particular commit revision number to deploy.

Comment: @ Dainis Abols: I might be wrong what I exactly meant as I told I am totally new, but I am working on PHP, MySql and Apache application which I need to deploy using capistrano.

Comment: To deploy a specific SHA:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918011/how-do-i-target-a-specific-commit-sha-with-capistrano-deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue. It was due to SSH account. I used following command "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" to resolve it.