# How to deploy a specific revision with capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

How can I deploy a specific git revision with Capistrano 3?

The Capistrano 2.9 approach doesn't work anymore

```
$cap -S revision=80655da8d80aaaf92ce5357e7828dc09adb00993 deploy
invalid option: -S
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The parameter seems to be gone in Capistrano 3. You have to set the env variable REVISION="revision" and include it in your deploy.rb

```
set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"]
```

Comment: In a multistage environment, you would probably include this in the environment files (e.g. `deploy/staging.rb` or `deploy/production.rb`).  And a cute ruby trick is to use `fetch` like this `set :branch, ENV.fetch('branch', 'master')` -- if branch is specified use it, else deploy master as the default.

Comment: Calling `BRANCH_NAME=my_branch; cap staging deploy` doesn't seem to work though. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: or you could just do `ENV['REVISION'] || ENV['BRANCH'] || 'master'`