# Deploy rails app to production, why still using environment staging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, puma, capistrano3

I have deploy my rails app to production, but why it still using environment staging, my rails app still connect to staging database,link url still forward to staging app like email confirmation it should connect to production app.

I'm deploy using capistrano, puma, my server using nginx

Is there something missing ???

This is database.yml code

```rb
development:
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456

staging:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_staging
  pool: 8
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB_PW'] %>

test:
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456

production:
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database_production
  pool: 60
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB_PW'] %>
```

This is production.rb code

```rb
set :application, 'my rails app'
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, 'production'

set :deploy_to,  "/var/#{fetch(:user)}/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :server_name, "my-rails-app.com"

set :delayed_job_args, "-n 4"

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036175/how-to-deploy-a-specific-revision-with-capistrano-3
set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || 'master'

role :app, %w{deploy@1.2.3.4}
role :web, %w{deploy@1.2.3.4}
role :db,  %w{deploy@1.2.3.4}
server '1.2.3.4', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

This is deploy.rb code

```rb
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application,       "my-rails-app"
set :repo_url,          "git@github.com:user/my-rails-app.git"
set :user,              'deploy'
set :puma_env,          'staging'
set :puma_threads,      [1, 16]
set :puma_workers,      1

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.1'

set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, auth_methods: %w(publickey) }

set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache

set :ssh_options,   { forward_agent: true, auth_methods: %w(publickey) }

set :linked_files, %w{.env config/master.key config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/cache tmp/sockets tmp/export tmp/pids public/assets public/uploads config/locales/field_translation/medical_category}

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = 'bundle exec rake'
SSHKit.config.command_map[:runner] = 'bundle exec rails runner'
SSHKit.config.command_map[:sidekiq] = "bundle exec sidekiq"

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: Why this is,  set :puma_env,   'staging' ?

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I had to run:

```
cap production puma:config
```

Answer (score 0):

In deploy.rb add,

```
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

Comment: i have already change that line but it's still didn't work @2017kamb

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with these tools, but when you use `set :rails_env, 'production'`, can you check if there is an environment variable named `RAILS_ENV` and not `rails_env`? Because Rails will expect an environment variable named `RAILS_ENV`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be due to the puma_env. You have set the puma_env as staging in deploy.rb.
In production.rb it should be set as production as below

```
set :puma_env,          'production'
```

Comment: You can check the deployment logs of command `cap production deploy`. Is it having staging anywhere?